# Absolute path of SD Card in Sony Android Tablet

Tags: android

I want to store video in sony android tablet and then i want to get that path. So what is the absolute path of SD card in sony android tablet. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: using this path i want to play video from tablet SD card

Comment: my main question is, what is absolute path of SD card in sony android tablet where i stored a video???

Comment: Don't use absolute paths. You should be using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` or `Context.getExternalFilesDir()`. Your question may be asking for a path that's specific to a Sony Tablet but what if you want to also provide your app for other devices or if Sony (in the future) change their hardware? Do it through the API, DO NOT hard code a path.

Comment: Mister is there any absolute path??

Comment: MisterSquonks comment should be +100ed.

Comment: You don't even need to know whether the path is absolute or relative - it doesn't matter at all. Just as long as you don't hard code it into your application but use the methods that MisterSquonk told you about!

Comment: @MisterSquonk: I think your comment should read "Don't use `hardcoded` paths."

Comment: @lucky: Yes, there IS an absolute path for all devices but you shouldn't rely on it. Do you want to write code which will work on Tablet v1 but fails on Tablet v2 ??? Look at this link here and learn how to use the API to access external storage http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: @Thorsten: You are probably right. Too late to change my comment though.

Answer (score 1):

Progammatically you call getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() and that will be returned as a string.  This refers to external storage which could be internal storage if there is no SD card in I believe.

Comment: Is there any absolute path without using method??

Comment: /mnt/sdcard/  but if you try to do this directly you will want to do a try catch block in case it throws a FileNotFoundException when the sd card isn't in the phone

Comment: No encouragement given, just knowledge. Warning was given to catch any exception thrown.